# VSTO there are one way to lock/Hide excel vbproject

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto

with Visual Studio,

I created one VSTO project.
On the Thisworkbook_OnLoad I import my bas file with the code used from my program.

Right, all was well but, if the user show the vba code, he can see it because it's unprotect.

How I can protect/Hide/Lock the vba code from seeing after importing modules??

Comment: I'd convert the bas file to your VSTO project.

Comment: the bas files are 10 ,with some hundred code line that import data, format, calculate, add Pivot and charts.
I use VBA from much time but .net just from few month, to convert the code I need more time. It will be my goal but a step at a time.
Now if is possible to lock the vbproject, I'll be happy

Comment: Sounds like a fun conversion project. Would password protecting the VBA code work for you? I think I've been able to do that in the past. I'll see what I can find in my source files.

Comment: @aduguid good, I hope you can found something, eventually show me the way

Comment: @aduguid you found something? You can confirm me that it’s possible to lock/hide VBE project wihitout reopen the file??

Comment: I couldn't find anything in my recent projects. https://github.com/Excel-projects